# Show Images that has spaces in Image ASP.NET control

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I am setting an absolute path to Image control. This path is having spaces. After assigning the path to ImageURL property of the Image ASP.NET control, it does not show the image. I don't have option to remove the spaces as it is the requirement. Also, this path is outside the root directory(There is basically a FileUpload control that takes the file and then I am assigning the path to Image control).

Firstly is it possible to do. If yes how? Below are the code blocks relevant to the question

**Server Code**

```
target.ImageUrl = strImagePath;
```

where target is the Image control id

**File Path: C:\Users\WebMaster\Downloads\2 States Full Vedio Songs 720p Bluray Encodded By(Khanz)\Screenshoot\vlcsnap-2014-05-17-13h22m13s103.png**

**Rendered HTML**

```
<img id="target" alt="[Jcrop Example]" src="C:\Users\WebMaster\Downloads\2%20States%20Full%20Vedio%20Songs%20720p%20Bluray%20Encodded%20By(Khanz)\Screenshoot\vlcsnap-2014-05-17-13h22m13s103.png" />
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You don't provide a file path to an image. The image must be hosted by a web server and you must use a URL to access it, not a filepath to a random location on the HDD. This is because the HTML is sent to the client, and it can't open "C:\etc\etc" on your server. If you absolutely must host the image outside your web server, then use server side code to retrieve the image file, then serve it up via something like a Generic Handler (.ashx).

Comment: You probably shouldn't advertise/imply that you have BluRay rips on your hard disk either.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Manson. I was so wrong. The image has to be hosted on the web server to access. Actually, this is what I want to cut down. Uploading the image from local user path to server folder was taking time. But I forgot the basics. Re-writing your comment as answer.